# display custom user fields with twig?

Tags: theming, 8

I added for users a couple of fields : *field_telephonenumber* and *field_company*

how can i display them in user.html.twig or maybe page.html.twig

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can configure which fields are displayed in the view mode `compact`:

```
admin/config/people/accounts/display/compact
```

Then you can in twig display all fields with

```
{{ content }}
```

or single fields with

```
{{ content.field_example }}
```

To put a user in a page template you can use [Twig Tweak](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak):

```
{{ drupal_entity('user', 1, 'compact')
```

The third parameter is the view mode and you can use theme hook suggestions to catch this with your custom user twig to make adjustments of the user fields.

Comment: What part of it did not work? And don't change the question, so that the answer doesn't fit anymore.

Comment: I changed the page because i made a mistake but i tested your answer on both pages the {{ content.field_example }} didn't work

Comment: Your first question was about the user twig. This is, where you normally display user fields. If you now ask, how to display user fields in other twigs, like a page twig, this is too broad for an answer. You need to be more specific.

Comment: I tried to display it in a user.html.twig page but it didn't work so i wanted to try maybe with something else and still it didn't work. I'm sorry i should've edited my question to say on any page possible, thank you for your help

Comment: For user twig the key is to add the new fields to the view mode. For page I put one possible solution in the answer.

Comment: Thank you i made it but i had to add the fields in manage display before using them in twig